# repo init fails getting android source code

Tags: python, android-source

I have tried to get the source code of android (on Windows 7) via this tutorial:
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

At this step

> $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

I got this error message which I cannot solve yet:

> fatal: unable to start C:\Users\mike\myrepo.repo\repo/main.py
>   fatal: [Errno 8] Exec format error

I have set the environment variables to the python interpreter to path C:\python but this problem still remains. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that [the getting started page](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) says the build isn't supported under Windows, so it's possible the repo script won't work in Windows either. Are you trying to run it on plain Windows or in a Unix-like-environment such as cygwin or SUA?

Comment: I run it on plain windows not in cygwin or SUA.

You are right i did not know that this is not supported (at now) in windows 7, but how do i get the source code of android.jar to debug my applications under Windows 7? Before i had installed the IDE Galileo SE and now i was trying to build my apps in Helios EE because i read that this ide is better but i see that there are more problems for android as in galileo.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it! You should post those steps as an answer below and tick it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the problem.

1. I made a clean installation of Eclipse Indigo SE (better newer than older versions)
2. got the sources via http://vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html (2.4. Android Source Code)
3. created a new project, created the classes and copied all the contents in the new classes
4. configured the build path as it was before.

Maybe there was a problem in the .metadata directory or general in the project build files which   caused this problem (i have not changed my   source code in the new project).

Comment: Mark this solution as answer for your question, please!